# reindex df on axis with duplicates

Tags: pandas, reindex

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [0,0,0,1,1,1], "col2": ["a", "b", "c", "D", "E", "F"] })
```

and want to transform it in

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [0,1,0,1,0,1], "col2": ["a", "D", "b", "E", "c", "F"] })
```

How can I achieve this?

So far I have tried

```
df.reset_index()
```

resulting in

```
index  col1 col2
0      0     0    a
1      1     0    b
2      2     0    c
3      3     1    D
4      4     1    E
5      5     1    F
```

and

```
df_test.reindex()
```

which did not change the df at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom sorting with help of [`grouby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) as `key` to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and a stable sorting method:

```
df_new = df.sort_values(by='col1', key=lambda x: df.groupby(x).cumcount(),
                        kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
```

Or with [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
df_new = df.iloc[np.argsort(df.groupby('col1').cumcount())]
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0     0    a
1     1    D
2     0    b
3     1    E
4     0    c
5     1    F
```

This works by creating an intermediate sorter key that will be used to reindex your rows:

```
df.groupby('col1').cumcount()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This works, thanks! But Is there a way to do this in an agnostic fashion, i.e. keep the original df if a unit test requires that as an outcome, and change it to df_new if this is the desired result? In other words, change the order purely relying on using "col1" as an index?

Comment: @user21402593 I'm not sure I follow you, can you give a more concrete example? In any case this process doesn't mutate the input so you can chose to keep it or replace it

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('col1', key=lambda x: df.groupby('col1').cumcount(), ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   col1 col2
0     0    a
1     1    D
2     0    b
3     1    E
4     0    c
5     1    F
```

**How it working**:

```
print (df.groupby('col1').cumcount())
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    2
dtype: int64
```